# DrawDib StretchDIBits which one is faster?

Tags: performance, stretchdibits, drawdib

I've never used DrawDib APIs,
My Application's UI rendering is based on stretchDIBits.
Because there are really lots of large images to draw , the stretchDIBits's (HAFTONE is used to get better render result) performace is bad...

I heard about  DrawDib is a group of efficient APIs to draw DIBs to DC. Is it better than stretchDIBits?

Can anyone give me some comparision document of them?
If the question is stupid, I am sorry. I really have very little experience about this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms704990(VS.85).aspx)?

> Collectively, the DrawDib functions
>   are similar to the StretchDIBits
>   function in that they provide
>   image-stretching and dithering
>   capabilities. However, the DrawDib
>   functions support image decompression,
>   data-streaming, and a greater number
>   of display adapters.
>
> You will find it beneficial to use the
>   DrawDib functions in some
>   circumstances. Still, StretchDIBits is
>   more diverse than the DrawDib
>   functions and should be used when the
>   DrawDib functions cannot provide the
>   desired functionality. The following
>   list describes factors to consider
>   when deciding whether to use the
>   DrawDib functions or StretchDIBits.

Comment: Thanks! I think this DrawDib is better.